Why are IPv6 address being assigned although IPv6 has been disabled (Debian 10 and 11)?
Although I've disabled IPv6 using /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

IPv6 addresses still show up on the ethernet interface which is configured statically with an IPv4 address in the local 192.168.1.x subnet.
The interface is also plugged into a hub that is connected to a router which I believe is IPv6 enabled. It is also configured with a static IPv4 address in the router's subnet which is different from the local subnet, ie 192.168.23.x, not the 192.168.1.x subnet.
Is it likely that the router is assigning IPv6 address to the ethernet interface via DHCP, or is it Debian itself allocating the IPv6 address and setting the default route to the router?
I'm even able to ping the local addresses from remote systems which I find rather worrying and whatsmyip.net displays one of the IPv6 addresses.

The IPv6 design comes with autoconfiguration capabilities. Are the addresses you see link-local or global?

@MarcusMüller I've disabled it manually but I'm sure they were global.

ah, sad, there goes my lead :)

@MarcusMüller I executed the sysctlcommands to disable IPv6 whence the disappeared immediately. After some time 2 of them have come up again and they end with   prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>. After rebooting they are still present, and I'm sure after some time at least an additional 8 will show up.

ah, maybe IPv6 RA?

@MarcusMüller What is IPv6 RA (I can do some reading on this), and more importantly why should it be able to override the disabling of IPv6 in sysctl.conf?

IPv6 Route Advertisement; essentially, say, your ISP gives you a /56 block of addresses, then your router can "delegate" for example a /64 subnet of that to your computer

@MarcusMüller What I don't understand is why it is allocated global IPv6 address when the kernel has been set to disable IPv6? I believe I had done everything in sysctl.conf to disable IPv6. Are there some other settings in Debian that can override this?
I have had to unplug the cables connecting directly to the router in order the disable the automatic IPv6 settings and link to it by wireless only.
