What other subsystems are responsible for enabling IPv6 in when it has been disabled in sysctl.conf, and how can I track which one is enabling it?
Although I have disabled IPv6 in sysctl.conf (Debian 11), connecting my main switch to an IPv6 enabled router results in IPv6 addresses being allocated on Debian interfaces and I can ping and SSH to them from external IP addresses.
The original problem is discussed in Why are IPv6 address being assigned although IPv6 has been disabled?.
Normal internet connection is via a box which connects to the router via wireless and is also connected to the main switch. It is the gateway for all the systems and runs the VPN.
The router normally has no direct connection to the main network switch.
The problem comes when I connect the router directly to the main switch so the box acting as the gateway can get a higher performance over the wired connection compared to the wireless.
Because IPv6 is disabled in /etc/sysctl.conf I don't expect IPv6 to be enabled at all, but it seems Debian has different ideas and whether via DHCPv6 or some other mechanism all the systems are allocated IPv6 addresses.
This results in internet connectivity going directly through it the router and bypassing the IPv4 based VPN, resulting in a lot of Cloudflare checks and some websites not working properly until I disconnect the cable connecting directly from the switch to the router and restart networking on the systems or reboot them altogether.
Checking whatsmyip.net displays my local IPv6 address and this is something I definitely don't want.
I suspect it may be possible to configure something on the router to disable the IPv6 though, but I'd rather leave that alone and disable it in the Debian configurations.
Are there other network services or some kernel features that bypass /etc/sysctl.conf and enable IPv6 to come up, either by DHCP or some other mechanism between Debian and the router?
PS. The systems involved are all Debian 10 and 11.

"Because IPv6 is disabled in /etc/sysctl.conf..." Can you show us what sysctl settings you have to disable ipv6 access?

For what it's worth, when I set net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1, it appears to be impossible to add ipv6 addresses to an interface.

@larsks The settings are listed in the linked question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/776581/26026. I suspect something feature of IPv6 called router advertisement. May be the issue. I will look into that as well.

Programs running with root privileges can manipulate sysctl settings.
Use e.g. sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 or cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 to verify that IPv6-disabling settings are actually still in place. Something like NetworkManager might be "helpfully" changing those settings to match its own IPv6 enable/disable status.
If ipv6 is loaded as a module, you could create a file named /etc/modprobe.d/disable-ipv6.conf with the following line:
options ipv6 disable=1

Then rebuild your initramfs and reboot.
Unlike the sysctl-based method, this has the advantage that once the ipv6 module has been loaded with the disable=1 option set, it cannot be re-enabled without rebooting. That should give you a stronger guarantee that IPv6 stays disabled, if you absolutely don't want it. (You cannot just block the module from loading, as things like iptables connection tracking functionality will require that the ipv6 module is loaded.)
When you have successfully done this, the kernel boot messages in dmesg output will include this line:
ipv6: Loaded, but administratively disabled, reboot required to enable

Note that if you do this, you may need to tell some programs to explicitly use IPv4 only. For example, Postfix will need a postconf -ev inet_protocols=ipv4 and a restart of Postfix to avoid an error condition when IPv6 is disabled in this way.

Thanks for the answer. How do you find out whether ipv6 is loaded as a module, and what class of settings require the initramfs to be rebuilt?

Run lsmod | grep ipv6. If it shows any output, ipv6 is loaded as a module; if no output, it must be built into your kernel. Anything that is loaded before the root filesystem is mounted must take its settings from initramfs; rebuilding initramfs (sudo update-initramfs -u in Debian) should never be harmful, and copies the updated /etc/modprobe.d settings into initramfs, so the ipv6module will always get the disabling option, even if something (e.g. firewall initialization or optional initramfs SSH support) causes it to load very early.
